# EventMachine - Port is in use

Tags: ruby, linux, networking, port, eventmachine

Getting a port is already in use error.

```
require 'em-websocket'
EM.run {
    EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "192.168.1.100", :port => 9001) do |ws|
        # Code goes here...
    end
}
```

Then on the same server at the same time but **different IP Address**:

```
require 'em-websocket'

EM.run {
    EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "192.168.1.101", :port => 9001) do |ws|
        # Code goes here...
    end
}
```

Then I get this error... Ports should bound to separate IP addresses, and thus be available to use.

`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in 'start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)`

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

Running: `netstat -tulpn | grep ruby` shows:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      718/ruby
```

Clearly shows the server is bound to `0.0.0.0` And Not `192.168.1.100`

How can I get `eventmachine` to bind to `192.168.1.100`?

Seems like a bug...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Afaik `0.0.0.0:9001` means that the port is bound on **every** available IP address. So it is conflicting with `192.168.1.100:9001`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is the problem. But how can I get EventMachine to not bind to `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: Exit of kill the running process on 0.0.0.0:9001 and I bet you are able to start EventMachine on 192.168.1.100:9001.

Comment: Wow, I was being really dumb and did was actually telling eventmachine to bind to `0.0.0.0`. I give you credit for helping me think more on this problem.